# one git bare repository used for many clone

Tags: git, branch, tagging

Is it possible to use the same git bare repository to hold data for different repositories? In other words, can I:

create a git bare repository (called BARE REPO)

clone it with master branch data from REMOTE REPO A

- git clone -b consolidate --single-branch git@444.444.44.44:ConsolidateService.git
- exec git add .
- touch README.md
- exec git commit -m "add README"
- exec git remote add consolidate
  ssh://root@333.333.33.33/var/repos/app.makeatoy.git
- exec git push consolidate master

erase the contents of BARE REPO

re-clone it with master branch data from REMOTE REPO B

- git clone -b test --single-branch git@444.444.44.44:TestService.git
- exec git add .
- touch README.md
- exec git commit -m "add README"
- exec git remote add testing
  ssh://root@333.333.33.33/var/repos/app.makeatoy.git
- exec git push testing master

erase the contents of BARE REPO

re-clone it with master branch data from REMOTE REPO C

- git clone -b prod --single-branch git@444.444.44.44:ProdService.git
- exec git add .
- touch README.md
- exec git commit -m "add README"
- exec git remote add production
  ssh://root@333.333.33.33/var/repos/app.makeatoy.git
- exec git push production master

If it is possible, how would one erase the contents of a bare repository?

TIA

Comment: In the bare repository, wanted to use the post-receive hook by 1) getting the name of the repository and 2) get the name of the branch used. Then, the idea was to generate a place to deploy web code to. Ex: For repository app1 / branch : test, the code would be deployed to directory app1-test. For repository app1 / branch prod, the code would be deployed to directory app1-prod, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create a bare repo and just add the remotes from different projects. To git, it's just unrelated branches. No need to delete anything after you fetch from each one (there's no working tree on a bare repo so nothing to delete.).

Comment: Thanks for the response :-) So, when you push data to a bare repository, where does it go? Is it like pushing something to /dev/null once the operation is complete?

Comment: It goes into the repo. But inside a bare repo there's nothing to delete. It's like a database. There are no "end user files" for you to add/modify/commit/remove, etc.

Comment: Just so we are clear: of course... there is information inside a bare repo. But if you push something into it, then delete whatever is inside of it (all the files that git uses to hold repo metadata like objects and references, config file, etc) then you end up with.... well, nothing. You can init --bare it again if you want. It would only be an empty directory.

Comment: Thanks again for the responses. So - when I push data (originating from repository Alpha)  into the master branch of the bare repository, the data stays there. If - sometime later,  I push data (that originates from Repository Beta)  - into the master branch of the same bare repository, then what would happen :-|

Comment: If the branch you are trying to push onto the repo has the same name, the branch would start pointing to the new branch. The information for the branch of the other project would remain on the repo (at least for a long while until there's some git-gc run that gets rid of it). Keeping two projects on the same repo is not the best thing you can do but if you want to keep branches called "master" from both projects on the same repo, you should use a prefix for the name so that they don't step on each other's toes: projectA/master, projectB/master. It's possible. Messy, but technically possible.

Comment: Thanks for the input :-))